# forgot password tank_auth codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, tankauth

i use tank auth as login handler in code igniter. when i use the forget password feature, i get a link send by mail `http://xx.xx.xx/en//auth/reset_password/2/01b951fd2a02efa2d64f1fe70c2a4e3b`. When i click this link it always says: "Your activation key is incorrect or expired. Please check your email again and follow the instructions."

i changed the segments so it gets the right segments but somehow it the goes wrong on `if ($this->form_validation->run())`. it Somehow wants the `new_password` and `confirm_new_password` as post data but from the link in the email no post data will ofcourse be sent.

Is this a bug in tank auth, is there a quickfix (does tank_auth forget a step, is something not configured right?)

reference code:

```
function reset_password()
{
    $break =$this->uri->total_segments();
    $new_pass_key= $this->uri->segment($break);
    $user_id= $this->uri->segment($break-1);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('new_password', 'New Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length['.$this->config->item('password_min_length', 'tank_auth').']|max_length['.$this->config->item('password_max_length', 'tank_auth').']|alpha_dash');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_new_password', 'Confirm new Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|matches[new_password]');
    $data['errors'] = array();

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) { //breaks here. For some reason wants to validate post data which
        if (!is_null($data = $this->tank_auth->reset_password($user_id, $new_pass_key,$this->form_validation->set_value('new_password')))) {    // success

            $data['site_name'] = $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth');

            // Send email with new password
            $this->_send_email('reset_password', $data['email'], $data);

            $this->_show_message($this->lang->line('auth_message_new_password_activated').' '.anchor('/auth/login/', 'Login'));

        } else {                                                        // fail
            $this->_show_message($this->lang->line('auth_message_new_password_failed'));
        }
    } else {
        // Try to activate user by password key (if not activated yet)
        if ($this->config->item('email_activation', 'tank_auth')) {
            $this->tank_auth->activate_user($user_id, $new_pass_key, FALSE);
        }

        if (!$this->tank_auth->can_reset_password($user_id, $new_pass_key)) {
            $this->_show_message($this->lang->line('auth_message_new_password_failed'));
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('auth/reset_password_form', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `new_pass_key` and `$user_id` are wrong I guess.

It should work out of the box with this:

```
$user_id    = $this->uri->segment(3);
$new_pass_key   = $this->uri->segment(4);
```

EDIT:

```
$user_id    = $this->uri->segment(4);
$new_pass_key   = $this->uri->segment(5);
```

Why did you change that by the way?

Comment: i added localization so the url got `/en/` in it on default. so i changed the code to take the last 2 segements, this code works fine

Comment: That should just work fine if there's a segment more in the url.

Comment: what `date_default_timezone_set` have you set in your index.php? that could be a problem too.